# Why does my .so have undefined symbols

Tags: c, dll, linker, shared-libraries, dlopen

Im creating a runtime loaded shared object in linux that impliments some JSON using jannson.h.

This is how I'm building the .so:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c device_simulator_json.c

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,device_simulator_json.so.1 -o device_simulator_json.so.1.0 device_simulator_json.o
```

When my application tries to load the .so, I get an error indication:
    undefined symbol: json_object

I'm guessing that my .so has to include in it the jansson object. But I'm not sure which one or how. I can see the following jansson objects in my /usr/local/lib:

```
./usr/local/lib/libjansson.so.4.7.0
./usr/local/lib/libjansson.so.4
./usr/local/lib/libjansson.a
./usr/local/lib/libjansson.so
```

Because the .so I'm building is dynamically loaded at runtime (using dlopen), doesn't the jansson object I use also have to be built with PIC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should link `libjansson.so` inside your shared library:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,device_simulator_json.so.1 \
  -o device_simulator_json.so.1.0 device_simulator_json.o  -ljansson
```

Alternatively, you might link `-ljansson` into the main program (doing the `dlopen`). You'll better then link that program with `-rdynamic`

BTW, you probably should compile your shared object with all warnings and debug info:

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -fPIC -c device_simulator_json.c
```

once all is debugged you might optimize with `-O2`